# len function - counting the # of letters in words

Tags: python-3.4

In Python, the len() function does provide the exact # amount of letters that make up a word in a string.

But when i have a string with multiple words, it doesn't display the correct # amount of letters because it is counting the spaces between the words.

what would be the correct command for the len() function to calculate the number of letters correctly for a string with multiple words ?

Comment: What if there are punctuation marks, or numbers?   What about newlines?  Please specify exactly what you want to count.

Comment: no punctuation marks, or numbers, just simply words.  the string is an answer to a street name. E.G.  Curve Avenue

Answer (score 0):

Remove all spaces before counting length:
 `string = string.replace(' ', '')`

Comment: So are you saying to do this before entering the len function ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: So are you saying to do this before entering the len function ?  starts with a string that aske a question.  the string that im talking about was assigned as variable to an input() function.  this is the command sRoad=input() ,   by the command you placed above, would it be sRoad = sRoad.replace('  ', ' ') ?  is the 1st Quotation Mark a double space between, and the second quotation mark a single space between ?

Comment: Great, I did what you said. The quotations i see are double for the first, and single for the second.  it worked good Thanks alot !

Comment: It was one space in the first quotations and no space in the second. So this function would replace every space in the `string` with no space, e.g. it would remove all spaces from the string. PS. If your question was answered, mark it as answered :)

Comment: reall? i did 2 spaces for first quotation, and 1 space for second quotation, and it worked find.   yes this is my first time in stackoverflow, where would i mark it answered ? i dont see the answer question button displaying anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `len([c for c in  address if c.isalpha()])`  Here I'm assuming that your string is named address. Here is the defininition of `isalpha` from the python 3.4 docs:

> Return true if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there
>   is at least one character, false otherwise. Alphabetic characters are
>   those characters defined in the Unicode character database as
>   “Letter”, i.e., those with general category property being one of
>   “Lm”, “Lt”, “Lu”, “Ll”, or “Lo”. Note that this is different from the
>   “Alphabetic” property defined in the Unicode Standard

We perform this test for each one-character string in the address.  Since python 3 strings are in Unicode, this test would also catch letters from other alphabets like Greek, Arabic, or Hebrew. I don't know if that's what you want, but if you only have letters from the English alphabet, it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks alot i'll try it also.

Comment: `isalpha()` will give a wrong result on street names like "14th Street" (in Manhattan)

Comment: @Alex S. I don't think so.  I asked the OP if he wanted to count numbers and punctuation marks, and he answered "Just letters."

Comment: @saulspatz Okay, but he may have forgotten that not only buildings have numbers,  street names may have numbers too.

Comment: @Alex.S That's right, of course, and it's why I asked, since he said "letters" in his question.  I asked him to specify what he wanted to count, and I wrote to his spec.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression :

```
import re

s = "14th Street 456 */\&^%$-+#@!()[]{};.,:"

# Remove anything other than letters
n = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]', "", s)

print(n)
print("length :" , len(n))
```

output :

```
thStreet
length : 8
```